# Windows Desktop Duplication API taking a long time

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I am using the windows desktop duplication API to record my screen in windows 10. I am however having some issues with performance. When playing a video using google chrome and attempting to record the time it takes to record the screen fluctuates from 15ms to 45ms. I wanted to be able to record at at least 30fps, and I know the desktop duplication api is capable of doing it. Anyways here is the code I used to actually capture the screen:

```
processor->hr = processor->lDeskDupl->AcquireNextFrame(0, &processor->lFrameInfo, &processor->lDesktopResource);

    if (processor->hr == DXGI_ERROR_WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
        processor->lDeskDupl->ReleaseFrame();
        return false;
    }

    if (FAILED(processor->hr)) {
        processor->lDeskDupl->ReleaseFrame();
        return false;
    }

    // QI for ID3D11Texture2D
    processor->hr = processor->lDesktopResource->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&processor->lAcquiredDesktopImage));
    if (FAILED(processor->hr)) {
        processor->lDeskDupl->ReleaseFrame();
        return false;
    }

    processor->lDesktopResource.Release();
    if (processor->lAcquiredDesktopImage == nullptr) {
        processor->lDeskDupl->ReleaseFrame();
        return false;
    }

    processor->lImmediateContext->CopyResource(processor->lGDIImage, processor->lAcquiredDesktopImage);

    processor->lAcquiredDesktopImage.Release();
    processor->lDeskDupl->ReleaseFrame();

    // Copy image into CPU access texture
    processor->lImmediateContext->CopyResource(processor->lDestImage, processor->lGDIImage);

    // Copy from CPU access texture to bitmap buffer
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE resource;
    processor->subresource = D3D11CalcSubresource(0, 0, 0);
    processor->lImmediateContext->Map(processor->lDestImage, processor->subresource, D3D11_MAP_READ_WRITE, 0, &resource);

    BYTE* sptr = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(resource.pData);
    BYTE* dptr = processor->pBuf;
    UINT lRowPitch = min(processor->lBmpRowPitch, resource.RowPitch);

    for (int i = 0; i < processor->lOutputDuplDesc.ModeDesc.Height; i++) {
        memcpy_s(dptr, processor->lBmpRowPitch, sptr, lRowPitch);
        sptr += resource.RowPitch;
        dptr += processor->lBmpRowPitch;
    }
```

It is important to note that this is the specific section that is taking 15ms-45ms to complete every cycle. The memcpy loop at the bottom accounts for about 2ms of that time usually so I know that that is not responsible for the time it is taking here. Also AcquireNextFrame's timeout is set to zero so it returns nearly immediately. Any help would be greatly appreciated! The code pasted here was adapted from this: https://gist.github.com/Xirexel/a69ade44df0f70afd4a01c1c9d9e02cd

Comment: Nothing went wrong, that's about what to expect when you try to duplicate output from a video player.

Comment: So how would you suggest one goes about recording the screen in windows if not by the Windows desktop duplication API? How do programs like fraps handle it? I can record video players just fine in fraps without any lag...

Comment: @ktb92677 Are you sure fraps copies uncompressed frames from GPU to system RAM like you're doing? The good way to record video is use hardware video encoders built-in in all modern GPUs.

Comment: Could you give an example of that?

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the API in optimal way. [Read remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgioutputduplication-releaseframe#remarks) in ReleaseFrame API documentation:

For performance reasons, we recommend that you release the frame just before you call the IDXGIOutputDuplication::AcquireNextFrame method to acquire the next frame. When the client does not own the frame, the operating system copies all desktop updates to the surface. This can result in wasted GPU cycles if the operating system updates the same region for each frame that occurs.

You are not doing what's written there, you release frames as soon as you copy.

Comment: Hi, I have made that adjustment to my code. But I am still seeing poor performance. What else should I try?